# Oracle SQL Developer, Execute Script won't stop running

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to write insert statements in Oracle and suddenly it stopped. I don't receive any error message, but the scriptRunner task won't stop running and I can't insert anything.

I've cancelled and paused the task, but it results in Oracle freezing and I have to force quit.

[image]

Update: I can run `select * from table` queries perfectly fine, but my individual insert statement is when I see this issue

Comment: what were you executing? For example, was it like 10,000 individual INSERT statements? or a script that generate INSERTs, or a INSERT AS SELECT?

Comment: I was attempting to add 4 individual insert statements:  

'INSERT INTO candidate(candidateID, college, major, candidateRecruiter, contactID)
VALUES ('CAN3846475', 'Saint Josephs University', 'Marketing', 'EMP8364922', '2');'

Comment: I've been adding a ton with the same formatting and this is correct with my data types... It just will not stop running and add

Comment: That should run VERY fast, like sub second. If it's just sitting there, it's possible there is a blocking event holding up the transaction.

Comment: how would I find out what is blocking it?

Comment: open a second connection to the same database in sql developer, and find your session in the Tools - Monitor Sessions page. Then click that session, and see the 'Contention' page below

Comment: also look at the Waits page, in the same 'monitor sessions' report'

Comment: I ended up completely disconnecting from the server I was on and setting it up again! thank you @thatjeffsmith

Comment: the problem is oracle sql developer, try with dbeaber

Answer (score 0):

This happens when some users have active or open sessions. They might have done some updation and insertion and didn't commit, and their sessions are still active then the script runner keeps on running when querying for updation from your session or from any other session. This is because database doesn't allow updating the same table to avoid inconsistency. you are able to run select queries because that can't cause inconsistency.

There is one solution to kill other active sessions and then run your query.
This is done in this way:

Search for the active sessions as:

**SELECT SID, SERIAL#, STATUS, USERNAME, OSUSER, SERVER
FROM V$SESSION
WHERE status = 'ACTIVE'**

Now kill those sessions which are from other users as:

**ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '<sid, serial#>'**

sid and serial# value you will get from the first query.

After executing these 2 queries you will be able to run your own queries.

Answer (score 0):

#Solution1:
In other session execute:

```
set serveroutput on 
cl scr
declare
q varchar2(1000);
begin 

for i in  (select SID,SERIAL# from gv$session where USERNAME='YourUserName' and SQL_ID='YourSqlId') loop
select 'ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '''|| i.SID || ',' || i.SERIAL# ||','|| '@1'''||' IMMEDIATE;' into q from dual;
dbms_output.put_line(q);
end loop;
end;
```

Then Run all statements the have been appeared in result window.

#Solution2:
If the problem exits yet, then close sql developer sheet.